# VS2022 stuck at "Preparing data." step

Tags: c++, profiler, visual-studio-2022

i started a break point at the very beginning of my main function. after one step, the profiler start preparing data, but it never finishes.

[image]

I am currently using visual studio community 2022 v17.1.5. I tried running a simpler project and it works perfectly. but the current project that I ran on, is a big project. I don't think that would cause any problem since i did a break point at the beginning of the main function.

Is it my fault or is it visual studio's fault?

Comment: How long did you wait? I've found it takes half an age to prepare even the shortest of profiling sessions. I can be waiting around 10 minutes for about 30 seconds of profiling data.

Comment: i am still waiting

Comment: that is not even close to 30 second of profiling data

Comment: still 0 percent

Comment: Try playing around with the debug mode: mixed vs managed vs native. Helped me in the past to bypass weird quirks in the profiler.

Comment: @Sedenion can you give me more details? How can I do this?

Comment: The thing I mean is called "Debug Type" (in the toolbar) or ["Debugger Type"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-in-mixed-mode?view=vs-2022) in the project's properties in the "Debugging" section. It sometimes helps to select "Native" or whatever one wants instead of leaving it on the default "Auto".